# Parsley.JS - Get an error list using callback

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

In my project I don't want to display HTML errors, but throw an `alert()` with list of errors on formSubmit. I guess this should be done somehow by using `listeners:onFormSubmit` callback, however none of passed variables does not contain "clean" version of errors. Parsley documentation also lacks of this feature.

Answer (score 5):

As of version 2.8.0, you can access the error messages via `fieldInstance.getErrorsMessages()`

Example:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="" class="required" data-parsley-type="integer" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").parsley();

        window.Parsley.on('field:error', function(fieldInstance){
            // get messages & alert
            var arrErrorMsg = fieldInstance.getErrorsMessages();
            var errorMsg = arrErrorMsg.join(';');
            alert(errorMsg);

            // get name of the input with error
            alert(fieldInstance.$element.attr('name'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also take a look at the following question [Display parsley errors in bootstrap tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008008/display-parsley-errors-in-bootstrap-tooltip)

Comment: for newer verision of Parsley, use window.Parsley.on insted of $.listen to avoid warnning parsley.min.js:16 Parsley's pubsub module is deprecated; Check my answer.

Comment: How would you loop this to obtain a string/array of all of the results to then output ?

Comment: @AdamJones If you mean all the errors for the one error field, the var `arrErrorMsg` is already an array. If, on other hand, you are trying to fetch all errors from all fields you should probably use the event `form:error`

Comment: Are there examples of this anywhere @LuísCruz ? I'm still a bit stuck with this so made a new question if you care for some stackoverflow points?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409242/parsley-js-catching-all-errors-and-outputting-via-a-javascript-alert

Answer (score 1):

To solved warning

*parsley.min.js:16 Parsley's pubsub module is deprecated; use the 'on' and 'off' methods on parsley instances or window.Parsley*

Try this

```
window.Parsley.on('field:error', function () {
                // This global callback will be called for any field 
                //  that fails validation.
                console.log('Validation failed for: ', 
          this.$element.attr('name'));
            });
```